# Writer who writes a story realizes that it is being lived by some person

Tags: identify-this-movie

I'm trying to identify a film which I cannot recall completely, its about a writer who writes a story and realizes that it is lived by another person (a girl). He happens to meet her somewhere, and then realizes that the character he is writing about is lived as it is by that girl.

I guess towards the climax, his story demands that the girl should die in an accident but he cannot do it as now he has actually met that person.

Can anybody identify this film?

Answer (score 14):

This sounds exactly like [Stranger Than Fiction](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0420223/) except that the writer is a female and the character is a male.

Comment: Beat me to it. Darn these slow fingers!!!

Comment: Ah, I dismissed Stranger than Fiction because they seemed sure the character was a girl. It could be [Ruby Sparks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_Sparks), in this the writer meets the girl he created, but he doesn't write about her death.

Comment: If it's **NOT** Stranger Than Fiction, I'll eat my hat! One of them, at least. Maybe the Frosty the Snowman? I'm pretty drunk. NO. The Updo kinda looks like a piece a piece of cheddar. I change my answer. Meh.

Comment: +1 to Ruby Sparks. Sounds very close to what the OP suggested - except about the dying in the end.